# What actually happens when using FileInputStream instead of FileReader?

Tags: java, inputstream, fileinputstream

I have read [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/bytestreams.html) oracle java tutorial, which basically shows that you can copy a txt file either by using a `FileInputStream` or a `FileReader`. Although they recommend using the latter approach I have a question about.
I would like to know what happens in using the first approach using a FileInputStream which basically reads plain raw bytes.

from this [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html):

> `public class FileInputStream extends InputStream`
>
> A FileInputStream obtains input bytes from a file in a file system.
>   What files are available depends on the host environment.
>   FileInputStream is meant for reading streams of raw bytes such as
>   image data. For reading streams of characters, consider using
>   FileReader.

If it's meant to be reading only raw bytes and there is no `InputFileReader` which bridges byte into chars. How come that by only using `FileInputStream`, it still works?

Comment: The rule of thumb: you can't go wrong with a `FileInputStream`. If you don't have a specific need for text, use that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you pointed out a `FileInputStream` (or generally an `InputStream` is for reading raw data as bytes whereas a `FileReader` ( or generally a `Reader`) is for reading character data.

The `Reader` will translate read bytes into charcters for you. A `Reader` will either use the default platform encoding or the encoding given in the constructor for this translation.

Copying a text file with a `FileInputStream` works because on the disk even a text file only consists of bytes.

Comment: Ok so basically the bytes get converted into integers and then when reading them again from a FileOutputStream viceversa.?

Comment: @Rollerball when writing to a `FileOutputStream` you write the bytes directly (without conversion) to the disk.

Comment: @Rollerball the point is that, depending on the encoding, not every char fits into one byte (e.g. UTF-8 encoding). You won't see problems with FileInputStream until you leave the ASCII characters though. For copying though, it doesnt matter - copying all the bytes is what matters.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure what you are asking but I think what you are looking for is `InputStreamReader` ([link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStreamReader.html)) which is used to convert a stream of bytes into characters. Care needs to be taken when converting byte streams into character streams as unicode can (and often does) use more than one byte per character.

Answer (score 1):

A FileInputStream could be a Stream of Bytes from any File, e.g. a mp3 File: Its just the answer on "how do i get any file into my java runtime?".
The FileReader is ment for use with character Files like .txt formats. Ofcourse you can also use it with any file, but as you read characters with a FileReader you may run in coding errors. Remember bytes are encoded utf8 default characters are ascii.

Comment: "Ofcourse you can also use it with any file" <-- you are asking for trouble if you do that